# Can I have a main method from another Leiningen project?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, leiningen

I'm writing a framework. Hopefully I'd like implementing projects to use the main method for the framework.

In my demo project, in `definition.clj` I have:

```
(ns definition
  (:gen-class))

(def widget
  {:this :that})

(defn -main [& args] (prn "MAIN"))
```

In my `project.clj` file I have `:main ^:skip-aot definition`. When I `lein run` I get the expected

```
lein run
"MAIN"
```

When I `lein repl` I can see the `widget` and `-main` functions:

```
definition=> definition/-main
#object[definition$_main 0x3ce2a73f "definition$_main@3ce2a73f"]
definition=> definition/widget
{:this :that}
```

When I call `(all-ns)` I can see the namespace as `#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x64965348 "definition"]`.

Here's the problem: if I change the main method to that defined in another project (which is a dependency):

```
:main ^:skip-aot the-framework.core
```

The main method works. But the namespaces are no longer visible:

```
the-framework.core=> definition/widget

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: definition, compiling:(/private/var/folders/gc/_1drfv2n2m588qnq5xz35g080000gn/T/form-init8820469930602256143.clj:1:1325)
```

The only thing that changed was the `:main` value in the Leiningen `project.clj` definition.

Is there a way to change the main method to an namespace not defined in the project without breaking the namespaces in the project?

Comment: did you try to `(require 'definition)`?

Comment: Yes! That works! I can `(require 'definition)` and then access it. But it doesn't work with `:require` in the `ns` declaration. Ideas?

Comment: This is strange, because `:require` in ns declaration does pretty much the same as `(require ...)`. Can you show some of your code that causes the issue?